# Playing Audio with Python sounddevice in Raspberry Pi Zero W works Exactly once and then I need to reboot

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I was inspired by [this project](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/turn-a-rotary-phone-into-google-assistant-with-raspberry-pi) to put a Pi into an old rotary telephone. I'm using python to bring it to life and perform the functions I would like to perform.  The first of these is pretty simple: play a dial tone when I pick up the receiver.

However, when I try to play audio using the sounddevice module, it will work the first time, and then stop working. And when I say stop working, I can no longer play audio with `aplay` or `speaker-test` or anything else until I reboot. It makes me think that something is not closing out correctly at the end of playback.

Hardware Setup:

- Raspberry Pi Zero WH
- [USB Audio Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IRVQ0F8)

Below is the code for my class, DialTone which is meant to be a thread run by my core application so it can start/stop the dial tone whenver necessary. At the bottom is a `main` meant to test the capability. It works just fine, over and over on Windows, but when I run it on the Pi: just once. Meanwhile I can `aplay` the same file over and over without issue (provided I haven't tried to play it with python).

Could it be that it's locking some resource and not releasing it? And somehow it's staying active after the process has exited?  Where would I look for that? What could it be?

```py
class DialTone(Thread):

    def __init__(self, input_queue:Queue, device:int_or_str ) -> None:
        """Initialize the dialtone class 

        Args:
            input_queue (Queue): A way to communicate with the thread
        """
        super().__init__()
        global _DIAL_TONE_FILE

        self.input_queue = input_queue
        sd.default.device = device

        # Commit the dial-tone data to memory so we can start/end quickly
        try:
            self.data, self.fs = sf.read(_DIAL_TONE_FILE, always_2d=True)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug( type(e).__name__ + ":" + str(e) )
    
    def run(self) -> None:
        """Play a dial tone in a continuous loop until we die
        """
        while( True ):
            cmd = self.input_queue.get(True)
            if( cmd == DialToneComms.DT_START ):
                logging.debug("DT: starting dial tone")
                sd.play(self.data, self.fs, loop=True)
                logging.debug(sd.get_status())
            elif( cmd == DialToneComms.DT_END ):
                logging.debug("DT: stopping dial tone")
                try:
                    sd.stop(ignore_errors=False)
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error( type(e).__name__ + ":" + str(e) )
                logging.debug(sd.get_status())
            elif( cmd == DialToneComms.DT_KILL ):
                logging.debug("DT: killing self")
                try:
                    sd.stop(ignore_errors=False)
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error( type(e).__name__ + ":" + str(e) )
                logging.debug(sd.get_status())
                break

# Test this capability
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--device",type=int_or_str,help="Audio device to use", default=1)
    parser.add_argument("--play_time",type=float,help="how long to play the dial tone",default=10.0)
    parser.add_argument("--num_cycles", type=int, help="Number of play, wait cycles", default=2)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Setup logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    dial_tone_queue = Queue()
    print( "Instantiating DialTone" )
    dial_tone = DialTone(dial_tone_queue, args.device)
    print( "Starting DialTone Thread" )
    dial_tone.start()

    # Play the dial tone a number of iterations
    for _ in range(args.num_cycles):
        print( "Playing dialtone for {} sec".format(args.play_time))
        dial_tone_queue.put(DialToneComms.DT_START)
        time.sleep(args.play_time)
        dial_tone_queue.put(DialToneComms.DT_END)
        
        print("Waiting 2 seconds")
        time.sleep(2)

    print("Kill the thread")
    dial_tone_queue.put(DialToneComms.DT_KILL)
    print("Joining DialTone")
    dial_tone.join(_JOIN_WAIT_TIME)

    if( dial_tone.is_alive() ):
        logging.warning( "Dial tone thread is still alive! What gives?" )
    else:
        logging.warning( "Dial tone thread is nice and dead")
```

Output of first run on Pi. The error at the bottom is a result of me stopping a stream that's not playing (the stop call already killed it, and the kill call is just making sure).

```
Instantiating DialTone
Starting DialTone Thread
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Kill the thread
Joining DialTone
DEBUG:root:DT: killing self
ERROR:root:PortAudioError:Error stopping stream: Invalid stream pointer [PaErrorCode -9988]
DEBUG:root:
WARNING:root:Dial tone thread is nice and dead
```

Output of 2nd Run on Pi. note that things start happening out of order, particularly after the stop, but audio never plays on the second time.

```
Instantiating DialTone
Starting DialTone Thread
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
Waiting 2 seconds
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
Waiting 2 seconds
Kill the thread
Joining DialTone
DEBUG:root:
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
WARNING:root:Dial tone thread is still alive! What gives?
DEBUG:root:
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
DEBUG:root:
DEBUG:root:DT: killing self
ERROR:root:PortAudioError:Error stopping stream: Invalid stream pointer [PaErrorCode -9988]
DEBUG:root:
```

Output on Windows:

```
Instantiating DialTone
Starting DialTone Thread
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:
Playing dialtone for 3.0 sec
DEBUG:root:DT: starting dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Waiting 2 seconds
DEBUG:root:DT: stopping dial tone
DEBUG:root:
Kill the thread
DEBUG:root:DT: killing self
Joining DialTone
ERROR:root:PortAudioError:Error stopping stream: Invalid stream pointer [PaErrorCode -9988]
DEBUG:root:
WARNING:root:Dial tone thread is nice and dead
```

Comment: You don't say which version of `pulseaudio` you are using but the module `load-module module-switch-on-connect` can play havoc with certain setups. Check `/etc/default.pa` and `$HOME/.config/pulse/default.pa` to see if it's loaded and if so with which options. https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/

Comment: Hi!  So I don't have any of those config files, and there doesn't seem to be an PA modules loaded--I believe PortAudio is included in the sounddevice python module. pactl isn't even installed.

Comment: It's important when you ask a question and add the relevant `tags`, that they are accurate. I was commenting on a question tagged `pulseaudio`. If as you say, you're not using `pulseaudio` edit the `tags` and you are more likely to get a relevant response.